# Custom UI which looks like design image

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a design Mockup of a remote control with 4 buttons and a Text Display. Now i want to create an Android Activity which looks like this mockup. How can i do this.
I think taking the design image as background for the activity is not the right way to do this (how would i make the buttons on the image clickable, etc...) 
Can anybody give me a hint how to start here?

kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You should create 9-patches(or patterns) for each graphic element on your layout for proper layouting on all available devices.
Then apply this patterns to your UI elemnt's(ImageView's, Buttons, TextViews) backgrounds.
Refernces:

1. http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html - 9-patch documentation
2. http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html - 9-patch creation
3. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html - Layouting

Answer (score 0):

You can use your background easily but the rest need to be done in Android.
First : download android sdk 
second : create your project
third : code :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with HTML, that should be kinda similar. You separate the cliclable parts from the background (the buttons), and make them `ImageView`, setting an `onClickListener`.

You'll need some Photoshop skills to do that, or ask a buddy designer to do that for you :)

Be careful with multiple screen support, since the background may get trickier to make it look right on every supported screen size.

Comment: But how would i position the buttons, etc. exactly where they belong to?

Comment: You position them relatively to the background. Let's say the red button is at coordinates 100, 230. You then create an ImageView that has, for example, marginTop=100 and marginLeft=230